# $|G:H|=p^n$ means $O_p(H)\leq O_p(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H\leq G$ (finite group) and $|G:H|=p^n$, ($p$ is a prime number) prove that: $$O_p(H)\leq O_p(G)$$

note: $O_p(G)$ defined as the intersection of all Sylow-$p$ groups in $G$

I try to prove $G_p\cap H\in Sylow_p H$, however it's not obvious and maybe wrong. And the proposition is definitely true if $H$ is normal( if $H$ is normal, we don't need the condition: $|G:H|=p^n$).

Comment: Does $G_p$ stand for the set of $p$-elements? If so then $G_p \cap H$ might be not even group. Take $G = S_4$, $H = S_3$, $p = 2$ and consider $(1, 2)(2, 3)$ for example.

Comment: @Orat ：$G_p\in Sylow_p G$ and $H_p\in Sylow_p H$ just a symbol. Sorry for this ambiguity.

Comment: Let $|H|=p^mq$, $|G|=p^{m+n}q$ where $(p,q)=1$. Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$, so $|P|=p^{m+n}$. Then, since $|G:H| = p^n$, $|P:P \cap H| \le p^n$, so $|P \cap H| \ge p^m$ and hence $|P \cap H| = p^m$ and $P \cap H \in {\rm Syl}_p(H)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : ok, thank you.